# Camera Intent auto crop like card IO? or Show a surface(dotted Line) and auto crop After Capture

Tags: android, camera, crop, surfaceholder, cardio

I am using Camera Intent to capture and Upload..For Default camera

So here I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779151/how-to-make-a-crop-camera-view-on-surfaceview-android) to crop image just like card IO..

But the above one is separate camera its not Intent

I want surface holder should be placed inside the camera intent .. is it possible if so can any one suggest me..

I want this surface crop before capture.... only for camera intent.. not for gallery... just like Card IO.... But for crop only...not OCR..

So I want to use the above functionality in this

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    return imageFile;
}
public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image*//*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        //chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        //chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "My_Camera");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".jpg");

        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image*//*");

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i,"Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,String acceptType,String capture) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }
}
```

Is it Possible can any one suggest me.. regarding this...

Here I have tried with Auto crop by placing intent for crop... but It show preview like surface from where to where its cropping.... for Default Camera through Intent..... Not for Custom Camera activity...